# gcm intent service failed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcast

In my gcm android app the app was successfully recieving data from server But I made some changes in onMessage() function of GCMIntentservice then applicaton crashes.Here I am giving the previous and changed onMessage() function.Please helpme to find the error

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");
        String message1 = intent.getExtras().getString("price1");
        String message2 = intent.getExtras().getString("price2");
        String message3 = intent.getExtras().getString("price3");
        String message4 = intent.getExtras().getString("price4");
        DatabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(getApplicationContext());
        int count = db.getRowCount_1();
        if(count > 0){
            db.resetTables_1();
        }
        db.addUser_1(message,message1,message2,message3,message4);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }
```

It was working.Then made some changes.

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        //String test1 = "instru";
        if (message.equals("instru")){
        String message1 = intent.getExtras().getString("price1");
        String message2 = intent.getExtras().getString("price2");
        String message3 = intent.getExtras().getString("price3");
        String message4 = intent.getExtras().getString("price4");
        String message5 = intent.getExtras().getString("price5");
        DatabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(getApplicationContext());
        int count = db.getRowCount_1();
        if(count > 0){
            db.resetTables_1();
        }
        db.addUser_1(message1,message2,message3,message4,message5);
       }
        else if(message.equals("signal")){
            //else {
            String message1 = intent.getExtras().getString("date");
            String message2 = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
            String message3 = intent.getExtras().getString("buy");
            String message4 = intent.getExtras().getString("stop");
            String message5 = intent.getExtras().getString("tv");
            String message6 = intent.getExtras().getString("tp");
            String message7 = intent.getExtras().getString("res");
            String message_type = intent.getExtras().getString("type");
            String message8 = "temp3";
            if(message_type.equals("1")){
                message8 = "Intra Day";
            }else if(message_type.equals("2")){
                message8 = "Short Term";
            }else if(message_type.equals("4")){
                message8 = "Short Term";
            }

            //DatabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(getApplicationContext());
            DatabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(getApplicationContext());
            int count = db.getRowCount_2();
            if(count > 0){
                db.resetTables_2();
            }
            db.addUser_2(message1,message2,message3,message4,message5,message6,message7,message8);


        }
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }
```

But this shows following error while running
logcat

```
03-25 02:27:00.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6258): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-211966293333-2]
03-25 02:27:00.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6258): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 02:27:00.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6258):     at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:52)
03-25 02:27:00.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6258):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
03-25 02:27:00.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6258):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
03-25 02:27:00.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6258):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 02:27:00.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6258):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 02:27:00.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6258):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-25 02:27:03.370: E/UnRegister Receiver Error(6258): > Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@41794160
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidhive.pushnotifications"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- Main activity. -->
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!-- Register Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<!-- Login Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: which one is line 52 (GCMIntentService.java:52) ?

Comment: if (message.equals("instru")){ @HenryChuang

Comment: @HenryChuang  if (message.equals("instru")){

Comment: @user3256431 your **message** string is null.

Comment: check "price", which send from your sever.